# Why variable can not be resolved

Tags: java, methods

I want this program to print a square of stars, but i can't even call one method from another, where is the mistake?

```
public class Main {
    private static void printStars(int amount){
        while(amount>0){
            System.out.print("*");
            amount--;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    private static void printSquare(int sideSize){
        while(sideSize>0){
            System.out.println(printStars);
            sideSize--;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printStars(3);
        printSquare(4);
    }
}
```

It is `System.out.println(printStars);` that tells me, variable can not be resolved

Comment: You're missing the () to make it a method call: `System.out.println(printStars(4));`

Comment: You need a pair of parentheses after the name of the method when you call it.  If the method has parameters (like these ones do), you need to put an expression inside the parentheses for each argument that you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

`printStars` is a method returning `void`. You cannot print it. Instead you should call it. Replace this line:

```
System.out.println(printStars);
```

with

```
printStars(sideSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not valid:

```
System.out.println(printStars);
```

**printStars** is not a variable, is a method, so you **could** print the result, but since the method is returning nothing (**void**) then is not even compiling...